# -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]' objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsarray

Hi all getting issues with if(indexPath.row==3) section is
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'. Cannot get where the issue is exactly. Below is my code

```
if(indexPath.row==3)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Subject";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"Subject"];
}
if(indexPath.row==3)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Education";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[empDict objectForKey:@"Education"];
}


NSArray *times = [empDict objectForKey:@"ClassTimings"];

NSString *stgmt = [[times objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"GMT"];

NSString *strtime = [[times  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Time"];

NSString *strtimeZone = [[times  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"TimeZone"];

NSString *str = [@[stgmt, strtime, strtimeZone] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
if(indexPath.row==3)
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Times To Take";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];

}

return cell;
```

Comment: why you used two times `NSString *str = [@[stgmt, strtime, strtimeZone] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
str = [@[stgmt, strtime, strtimeZone] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];`

Comment: its by mistake, edited bro

Comment: ok why you used three `if(indexPath.row==3)`

Comment: The message is pretty clear; you tried to access the 12th element of an array with 11 objects. Which line does the exception occur on?  Show your `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: I do not believe that you get the exception inside the "if(indexPath.row==3) section", since in none of them `objectAtIndex:` is sent.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik +1

Comment: Can you please clear how many section's and how many row's you have in tableview? Also share full code, so we all can come to know the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in `"if(indexPath.row==3)"`

You're getting error from any of bellow three line

```
NSString *stgmt = [[times objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"GMT"];

NSString *strtime = [[times  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Time"];

NSString *strtimeZone = [[times  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"TimeZone"];
```

where you are trying to access `12th element` (when value of `indexPath.row==12`) of the `'times'` array which don't have `12 elements`...

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because you've tried to access 12th element of an array of 11 elements.
 In your code, if `times` array doesn't have 12 elements and if you are trying to access 12th element, this issue can occur. That is if `indexpath.row = 12` and you try to access 12th object by `[times  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`leads to this error.